# Heroku log what's my error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

I've been trying to figure out what the error is when I deploy to heroku - I get the error:

`If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.`

on heroku.

When I check the logs, this is my output:

```
2014-12-04T19:11:39.601769+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by ***@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:11:39.601769+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by ***@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:04.540163+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:04.540163+00:00 heroku[api]: Set LANG, RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, SECRET_KEY_BASE config vars by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:05.567740+00:00 heroku[api]: Set DATABASE_URL config vars by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:05.567772+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:05.646074+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY resource by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:05.646104+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:06.061846+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:06.164666+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:06.164619+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8dabf8a by **@gmail.com
2014-12-04T19:13:12.044424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 3629 -e production`
2014-12-04T19:13:15.049430+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-12-04 19:13:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-12-04T19:13:15.049452+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-12-04 19:13:15] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
2014-12-04T19:13:15.049770+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-12-04 19:13:15] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=3629
2014-12-04T19:13:15.467086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-12-04T19:13:45.069127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-sands-2102.herokuapp.com request_id=22e2e81b-39d4-4d63-9a30-b0b2c99aedc3 fwd="122.161.16.112" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=322ms status=500 bytes=1754
2014-12-04T19:13:45.878115+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-sands-2102.herokuapp.com request_id=8f5605ee-e29f-447a-a788-f553ab2f2ddb fwd="122.161.16.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=1829
```

So the status changes from 500 to 404 in the last two lines, but the site renders perfectly locally, but I can see a 500 and then a 404 on '/' on heroku

What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku log just says that your app generate 500 error on '/' root route and there is no favicon  .ico in public directory (404, file not found).

Maybe you must to set up Rails 4 logging to STDOUT first (so Heroku could print them)
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4#logging-and-assets

Comment: Thank you! Definitely got more clarity after I STDOUT'ed the damn thing!